# Model behavior trying to validate when it shouldn’t be

Tags: cakephp, model

I’ve created a simple model behavior in my CakePHP application to handle file uploads. In its `beforeValidate()` method I have the following:

```
public function beforeValidate(Model $Model, $options = array()) {
    $maxFileSize = '1MB';

    $Model->validator()->add($this->settings[$Model->alias]['field'], array(
        'extension' => array(
            'rule' => array('extension', $this->settings[$Model->alias]['allowedExtensions']),
            'message' => __('Please supply a valid image'),
            'allowEmpty' => ($this->settings[$Model->alias]['required'] === false)
        ),
        'fileSize' => array(
            'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', $maxFileSize),
            'message' => __('Image must be less than %s', $maxFileSize)
        ),
        'uploadError' => array(
            'rule' => 'uploadError',
            'message' => __('Something went wrong with the upload')
        )
    ));

    return true;
}
```

I’m dynamically adding file field-related validation. The first rule is checking the extension is in an allowed array of extensions passed in the behavior settings, and I’ve an `allowEmpty` key that equates to `true` because a file upload is not mandatory in this case.

This behavior is attached to an `Event` class. When editing an event, the extension validation rule kicks in, even though I’ve specified `allowEmpty` as `true`. Why is this?

Is it because the data passed in the file field is an array and actually equates to non-empty, therefore the validation is kicking in? If so, how can I combat this? I only want validation to kick in if a file has actually been uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it because the data passed in the file field is an array and actually equates to non-empty, therefore the validation is kicking in?

Yes. If no file is uploaded the array key for the model field will still be present, with a none-empty value. I.e. something like:

```
//$request->data
array(
    'Model' => array(
        'field' => array(
            ...
            'size' => 0,
            'error' => 4
        )
    )
);
```

### Coping with optional file uploads

To prevent problems validating a field which is a file upload - a simple option is to check for [UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) and wipe the relevant model data. In a beforeValidate callback that could look like this:

```
$field = $this->settings[$Model->alias]['field'];
if (
    isset($Model->data[$Model->alias][$field]['error']) && 
    $Model->data[$Model->alias][$field]['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
) {
    unset($Model->data[$Model->alias][$field]);
}
```

Alternatively add a bail-early chunk of code to all validation rules:

```
function validateExt($Model, ...) {
    $field = $this->settings[$Model->alias]['field'];
    if ($Model->data[$Model->alias][$field]['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Such that even if called with an empty file upload the validation rules do not return false negatives. Incidentally, validation rule-order matters, it would make more sense to check for an upload error - before validating the contents of the upload =).

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the tip on rule order too!